# Track status changes (prev,cur) in column "Adoption Ladder" groupBy "Account id"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Sample data:

```
   Account id    Adoption ladder
0         111     Awareness   
1         111     Awareness   
2         111     Awareness   
3         111     Awareness   
4         111     Restrict   
5         111     Restrict   
6         111     Restrict   
**7         222     Awareness  **
8         222     Restrict   
9         222     Avoids  


"Account id"
```

Below is my code, but the result column "changes From->To " isn't groupedBy "Account id", I want to find a way to groupBy this with "Account id"

My code:

```
data['changes From->To'] = ['no changes'] + [prev + ' --> ' + cur if prev != cur else 'no changes' for prev, cur in zip(data['Adoption ladder'], data['Adoption ladder'][1:])]
```

Results:
(Expected result: At row 7 i dont want to track it as a change because the "Account id" changes form 111->222)

```
            changes From->To        
0              no changes    
1              no changes 
2              no changes    
3              no changes    
4           Awareness->Restrict  
5              no changes   
6              no changes  
7           Restrict->Awareness **I dont want to track this as a change**
8              no changes  
9           Restrict->Avoids
```

Comment: What you want to achieve is quite unclear, what are the logic and the expected output?

Comment: at line 7,the account id has been change,so the output  at" changes From->To  ''(line 7) must be  Awareness->Restrict .It would be acceptable if the account id had not been changed.